# How to keep current page on ajax pagination after editting a row?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

The header.php has a `<div id="content"></div>` and then will load the page user.php

Q1: Is javascript coding on the header.php can not interact with the loaded content?
Therefore I put the js code on the loaded page, but i found a little bit strange.

Q2:
The paging function is  working, suppose it is on page 4.
After I editting one of the row, the page go back to first page. I want to keep it on page 4.

< 1 2 3 **4** 5 6>

I want to store the current link as a text within a   after i click the paging, however the link is stored first and then page will refresh and clear the data.

The href of the paging links will look like
localhost://blog/index.php/admin/users/show/10

localhost://blog/index.php/admin/users/show/20

localhost://blog/index.php/admin/users/show/30

Please point out the solution or suggest another better solution

```
  $("input[name=submit]").click(function() {
            $(this).parents('.alert-box').hide();
            $form = $(this).parent('form');
            $.post(
                    $form.attr('action'),
                    $form.find(':input').serializeArray(),
                    function(data) {
                        $("#content").html(data);
                    }
            );
        });
```

**View:header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href="<?= $css; ?>bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="<?= $css; ?>basic/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $js; ?>jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $js; ?>jquery_validate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $js; ?>form_control.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $js; ?>additional-methods.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            #content{
                background-color: #D0D0D0;
                float:left;
                width:80%;
            }
            #main-frame{
                width:100%;
            }
            #list{
                width:18%;
                float:left;
            }
            #delete-alert-box{
                background-color: #269abc;
                position: absolute;

                z-index: 99999;
                display: none;
            }
            #edit-alert-box{
                background-color: #269abc;
                position: absolute;

                z-index: 99999;
                display: none;
            }

            body{
                font-size:2em;
            }

        </style>
        <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                init();
                $('.open').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
                        $('#content').html(data);
                    });
                });

            });

            function init() {
                $.post(
                        "<?php echo site_url("admin/users/show");?>", function(data) {
                            $("#content").html(data);
                        }
                );
            }
        </script>

        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
            </div>
            <?php if ($this->AuthModel->check_admin_log()) { ?>
                <a href="<?= site_url('admin/users/logout') ?>">Logout</a>
            <?php }
            ?>
        </div>

        <ul id="list">
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/users/show') ?>" class="open">Users Manage</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/groups') ?>" class="open">Group Manage</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/blog_posts') ?>" class="open">Post Mange</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/system') ?>" class="open">System Setting</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('logout/admin') ?>" >Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="content" class="box"></div>
```

**view:users.php**

```
<table border="1">

    <tr><th>User Id</th><th>User Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Registeration Date</th><th>Group</th><th>State</th><th>Operation</th></tr>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $user->id; ?></td>
            <td><?= $user->username; ?></td>
            <td><?= $user->email; ?></td>
            <td><?= mdate('%Y-%m-%d', $user->registeration_time); ?></td>
            <td><?= $user->user_type; ?></td>
            <td><?= $user->account_status; ?></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>" name="delete">X</button>
                <button type="button" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>" name="edit">edit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>  

<?php echo $links ?>
<div id="delete-alert-box" class="alert-box">
    <div class="cancel">X</div>
    <h3>Are you sure to delete the account?</h3>
    <form action="<?php echo site_url('admin/users/delete') ?>" id="deleteForm">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="user_id">
        <input type="button" value="Yes" name="submit"> 
        <input type="button" value="No" name="cancel">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="edit-alert-box" class="alert-box">
    <div class="cancel">X</div>
    <h3>Edit User:<span id="username"></span></h3>
    <form action="<?php echo site_url('admin/users/edit') ?>" id="editForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Group</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="group" id="group">
                        <option value="1">Nomal User</option>
                        <option value="2">Amin</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="state" id="state">
                        <option value="1">Activated</option>
                        <option value="2">Non-Activated</option>
                        <option value="3">Blocked</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="user_id">
        <input type="button" value="Yes" name="submit"> 
        <input type="button" value="No" name="cancel">
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".cancel").click(function() {
            $(this).parent('.alert-box').hide();
        });
        $("input[name=cancel]").click(function() {
            $(this).parents('.alert-box').hide();
        });

        $("button[name=delete]").click(function() {
            var $user_id = $(this).attr('value');
            if ($user_id !=<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id') ?>) {
                $("#delete-alert-box").show();
                $('#delete-alert-box').find('input[type=hidden]').attr('value', $user_id);
            }
        });

        $("button[name=edit]").click(function() {
            var $user_id = $(this).attr('value');
            if ($user_id !=<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id') ?>) {
                $("#edit-alert-box").show();
                var $tr = $(this).parents('tr');
                var $tds = $tr.find('td');
                $('#edit-alert-box').find('input[type=hidden]').attr('value', $user_id);

                $('#group').find('option').each(function(index) {
                    $(this).removeAttr('selected');
                });
                $('#group').find("option[value=" + get_group_code($($tds[4]).html()) + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');

                $('#state').find("option[value=" + get_account_code($($tds[5]).html()) + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });

        $("input[name=submit]").click(function() {
            $(this).parents('.alert-box').hide();
            $form = $(this).parent('form');
            $.post(
                    $form.attr('action'),
                    $form.find(':input').serializeArray(),
                    function(data) {
                        $("#content").html(data);
                    }
            );
        });

        $('.paging a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
                $("#content").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
    function get_group_code(name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "Normal User":
                return 1;
            case "Admin":
                return 2;
        }
    }
    function get_account_code(name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "Activated":
                return 1;
            case "Non-Activated":
                return 2;
            case "Blocked":
                return 3;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Controller: admin/users.php**

```
function pagination() {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('admin/users/show');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->UsersModel->get_num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = '10';
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p class="paging">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    return $this->pagination->create_links();
}

public function show() {
    $data['users'] = $this->UsersModel->get_users(10, $this->uri->segment(4, 0));
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination();
    $this->load->view('admin/users', $data);
}

public function delete() {
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    if (!$this->UsersModel->delete_user($user_id)) {
        echo "Unknown error";
    }
    $this->show();
}

public function edit() {
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $state = $this->input->post('state');
    $group = $this->input->post('group');
    $data = array(
        'id' => $user_id,
        'account_status_code' => $state,
        'group_status_code' => $group
    );
    if (!$this->UsersModel->edit_user($data)) {
        echo "Unknown error";
    }
      $this->show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The paging function is working, suppose it is on page 4. After I
>   editting one of the row, the page go back to first page. I want to
>   keep it on page 4.

When opening that 4-th page in a browser, you can save its number in **session** and then after editing you can read that value you stored in session i.e - 4.

```
@session_start();

function indexAction()
{
   $_SESSION['curr_page'] = 4; // or take it from $_GET
}

function saveAction(){
  // .... do stuff....

  header('location: page.php?page=' . $_SESSION['curr_page']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first the best way to do paging is via get, to get the url friendly and rotating the User in case it needs to pass it on.
you need set data in console.log(), for view if data this value,
if the expected values ​​are coming up to the date, try switching by append html:
example.
$ ("# content") html ('.');
$ ("# content") append (date).;